# Multivariable functions

Tags: functions

I've read: 
“Graphs of functions of two variables,  are surfaces in three dimensional space.”

But equation of a line has two variables in it, and still we can draw its graph in two dimensional space .

Comment: A line $y=ax+b$ is a function of one variable, namely $x$. $y$ is just $f(x)$ is the function.

Comment: Equation $\neq$ graph of function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion probably lies in the difference between

"*a function of **two** variables*"

and the fact that the *equation* of a line in the plane contains the two cartesian coordinates $x$ and $y$.

Any line in the plane has a cartesian equation of the form $ax+by+c=0$ which can be solved for $y$ if the line is non-vertical. In that  case, it is also the graph of "*a function of **one** variable*" $y=f(x)$ with $f(x)$ of the form $mx+q$ in the case of a line.

Note that this is not the same as *a function of **two** variables*: $z=f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2):

The equation of a line is something like $3x+2y=4$. More precisely, the line is$$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,3x+2y=4\}.$$But this is a *set*, not a *function*. The graph of the function$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb{R}^2&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\(x,y)&\mapsto&3x+2y\end{array}$$*is* a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, namely the surface$$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,|\,z=3x+2y\}.$$

Comment: @ZahraaKhalife Right.

Comment: @ZahraaKhalife If my answer was useful, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @ZahraaKhalife There is *no* contradiction between my answer and the other one. Actually, you misread the other one, since it dos *not* say that it's a function of one variable. What it says is that it's the **graph** of a function of one variable.

Comment: @ZahraaKhalife If you want to see it that way, I don't think that there's anything wrong with it. But note that now you are talking of a function of *one* variable. Your original question was about functions of *two* variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63650/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-zahraa-khalife).